# Should I write different functions for every onPress

Tags: react-native

I have 16 boxes. Each boxes has their own TouchableOpacity.

How can I disable a button which is pressed already?

I used same function for all boxes. When I press one of them, all boxes work together.

How can I seperate them?

This is my onPress function.

```
onTap(){
  if(!this.pressed){
    this.pressed=true;
    let rastgele=Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.state.music.length));
    Linking.openURL(this.state.music[rastgele]);
    console.warn('pressed',rastgele);
   }
}
```

Boxes:

```
<View style={{MYSTYLE}}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onTap} style={{MYSTYLE}}>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}> 1 </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you guessed it yourself that your mistake is not differentiating between your boxes.

You can give an id to each button and track which button is pressed by its id in your state.

First initialise a state variable where you will track your changes:

```
state = {
    pressedBoxes: {}
}
```

Then change your onTap function to accept an id as an argument:

```
onTap = buttonId => {
    const { pressedBoxes } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      pressedBoxes: {
        ... pressedBoxes,
        [buttonId]: !Boolean(pressedBoxes[buttonId]),
      },
    });

    // ... Whatever other code you have should go here
};
```

Then finally use the state variables to disable your buttons:

```
<View style={{MYSTYLE}}>
    <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.onTap('1')}
          style={styles.MYSTYLE}
          disabled={this.state.pressedBoxes['1']}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}> 1 </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.onTap('2')}
          style={styles.MYSTYLE}
          disabled={this.state.pressedBoxes['2']}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}> 2 </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>


    <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.onTap('3')}
          style={styles.MYSTYLE}
          disabled={this.state.pressedBoxes['3']}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}> 3 </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

I'm sure there are other ways to solve your problem just use the state and improvise.

Comment: Thank you very much mate, I really appreciate that.